# Hive query on s3 partition is too slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I have partitioned the data by date and here is how it is stored in s3.

```
s3://dataset/date=2018-04-01
s3://dataset/date=2018-04-02
s3://dataset/date=2018-04-03
s3://dataset/date=2018-04-04
...
```

Created hive external table on top of this. I am executing this query,

```
select count(*) from dataset where `date` ='2018-04-02'
```

This partition has two parquet files like this,

```
part1 -xxxx- .snappy.parquet
part2 -xxxx- .snappy.parquet
```

each file size is `297MB.` , So not a big file and not many files to scan.

And the query is returning `12201724` records. However it takes 3.5 mins to return this, since one partition itself is taking this time, running even the count query on whole dataset ( 7 years ) of data takes hours to return the results. Is there anyway, I can speed up this ?

Comment: 1) Hive is not fast. Are you using MapReduce or Tez? 2) How large is the cluster? 3) Try Presto or Spark instead

Comment: 1. Hive execution engine is Tez. 2. Cluster size is 3 m3.xlarge nodes - not a big one though. But how this impacts ? Since the read is going to be from s3 ? 3. I will try presto now.

Comment: Thank you. :) Presto is what I need. It took 0.02 seconds to return the same result as above. Also, for the entire 6 billion records count, it took 1.15 mins. Thats amazing.

Comment: Having tough time connecting to presto using Tableau, any help or instructions for that please? And how good presto is in terms of scalability, if we build our production application on it. ?

Comment: I don't use Tableau. Setup a VPC and open up the port? If you have access to AWS/EMR support, that's a question for them

Comment: [`Issue with Hive Bucket Execution in Some Releases`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-considerations.html) seems related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Amazon Athena** is, effectively, a managed Presto service. It can query data stored in Amazon S3 without having to run any clusters.

It is charged based upon the amount of data read from disk, so it runs very efficiently when using partitions and parquet files.

See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Comment: Thanks. How good presto is in terms of scalability, if we build our production application on it. ? Any example applications or architecture for it?

Comment: presto scales horizantally.  You can use it as part of your EMR installation or you can use serverless Athena.  Many large companies lik e Netflix,Lyft use presto in production

Comment: "Presto was designed and written from the ground up for interactive analytics and approaches the speed of commercial data warehouses while scaling to the size of organizations like Facebook." — https://prestodb.io/

Comment: Thank you. But can it be quick to have it as a background for a web application? I tried to query 6 billion records with a Cluster  of size - 5 m3.xlarge nodes. But its taking 1.15mins. Users can't wait for 1.15 mins in a page. Is it not the right use case ?

Comment: Having said that, web application will only read and show, its a kind of aggregated reporting. No write on this.

Comment: I suggest you try Amazon Athena and do some speed comparisons for yourself.